# Print JSON object value from GitHub Workflow

Tags: json, github-actions

I have a workflow step that outputs the following:

```
{key_name:[]}
```

This is then used as a matrix operator as follows:

```
strategy:
   fail-fast: false
   matrix: ${{ fromJSON(needs.first_job.outputs.json_object) }}
env:
   ENVIRONMENT: ${{ matrix.key_name }}
```

The above is all working as expected, but I want to add a catch to see if the array is empty.

How can I access the array value at the second job definition?

If I do this, in the first job:

```
echo "${{ steps.generate-matrix.outputs.json_object }}"
echo "${{ fromJSON(steps.generate-matrix.outputs.json_object) }}"
echo "${{ fromJSON(steps.generate-matrix.outputs.json_object).key_name }}"
```

I get the following:

```
{key_name:[]}
Object
Array
```

Does anyone know why the fromJSON is printing the type as opposed to the values?

Comment: You need [`toJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) for that e.g. `echo '${{ toJSON(fromJSON(steps.generate-matrix.outputs.json_object).key_name) }}'`.